# Focus on paragraph with a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I focus on paragraph with `id` = `con3` in the following html code?

HTML:

```
<div id="dragnresize" contenteditable="true"></div>

<button OnClick="foc()">focus</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function foc()
{
    $("#dragnresize").append('<p id="con3" contenteditable="true" style="border:solid black 1px"></p>');

    var foc = $('#dragnresize').contents().find('p#con3').html();

    $(foc).focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `id selector` directly. why making the things complex.?

```
 $('#con3').focus();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I had already tried that out. Can you show me an example if it does

Answer (score 0):

use focus event selector of jQuery `$('#con3').trigger('focus');` Or `$('#con3').focus();`

**Update :WHY are you saying NOT working??? I tried :**

Using Trigger
http://jsfiddle.net/nz796jq1/

Using regular http://jsfiddle.net/nz796jq1/1/

Comment: It doesn't work. I had already tried that out. Can you show me an example if it does